# How to save multiple entries into an object through a PUT request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `onBlur` function that is going to send draft values from a lot of fields. The idea is to make an request everytime the user goes to the next field. The problem I have is that everytime I do a `PUT` request to `draftFields`, the previous value is replaced.

```
  const sendDraftHandler = (event, name, value) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userData = localStorage.getItem('pmm');
    const userId = JSON.parse(atob(userData)).id;
    axios
      .put(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/save-draft/${userId}`,
        {
          draftFields: { [name]: value },
        },
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        setError(true);
        console.log(error, 'error');
      });
  };
```

`draftFields` is an empty object from my user model(mongoDB).

The format of `name` and `value` is string.

This is the format that I have in mind for `draftFields`(I accept suggestions if my way of thinking is wrong):

```
draftFields: {
  "some name1": "some value1",
  "some name2": "some value2",
  "some name3": "some value3",
}
```

But at the moment, my `draftFields` object can hold only one key/value instead of multiple.

What I can do to save the previous value?

I'm using React if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved my issue creating an `useEffect` that is going to watch everytime `draftField` changes, instead of using a function bc `useState` is not async, so `draftField` was always empty.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const userData = localStorage.getItem('pmm');
    const userId = JSON.parse(atob(userData)).id;
    axios
      .put(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/save-draft/${userId}`, {
        draftFields: draftField,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        setError(true);
        console.log(error, 'oi?');
      });
  }, [draftField]);

        // onBlur usage
        <FormControlLabel
          inputRef={register}
          name="escopo-projeto--primeiro-site"
          control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
          label="Primeiro site"
          onBlur={() => {
            setDraftField({ ...draftField, primeiroSite: true });
          }}
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          inputRef={register}
          name="escopo-projeto--novo-site"
          control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
          label="Novo site"
          onBlur={() => {
            setDraftField({ ...draftField, novoSite: true });
          }}
        />
```